# .NET - Is there a singly-linked list in System.Collections.Immutable somewhere?

Tags: c#, .net, list, linked-list, immutability

In functional programming, singly linked lists are extremely popular, because it is easy to reuse sub-lists without allocating any memory or copying values.  This means you can add or remove items from one end without any allocation.  The F# list is like this.

From what I've read, it sounds like `System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableList<T>` is like an immutable version of `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`, which is an abstraction over arrays.  This is more optimized for random access than a linked list, but requires copying the entire list when adding or removing items.

`System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList<T>` is a mutable doubly-linked list, which means that either mutation and/or copying is required to add or remove items.

There is no `System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableLinkedList<T>` that I've been able to find.

Is there really no immutable singly-linked list in the `System.Collections.Immutable` package?  Is using `Microsoft.FSharp.Core.List<T>` the best option here?

Comment: This might interest you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10045677/84206

Comment: Is this useful to you? [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467186(v=vs.111).aspx)

Comment: I think ImmutableQueue might serve my use case, thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is (as of this writing), no great answer to this in the .NET base class library.

The closest thing in `System.Collections.Immutable` is `ImmutableStack<T>`, which is implemented as a singly-linked list under the hood. However, the exposed functions are very limited so unless you actually want a stack this is probably a poor choice. You are correct that `ImmutableList<T>` is a different datastructure with different operations and performance characteristics.

There is `FSharpList<T>` in the F# standard library, but due to being an F# primitive this is awkward to use from C# (it's possible, it just won't result in clean, idiomatic code). Also requires taking the full F# standard lib as a dependency.

Having faced the same problem in one of my projects, I wrote a [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ImmutableLinkedList) "ImmutableLinkedList" ([github here](https://github.com/madelson/ImmutableLinkedList)) for this, so that could be an option as well.